# highcharts hide the chart except the legend

Tags: javascript, css, highcharts

Is there a way that I could hide everything except the legend?

I tried doing this by this code:

```
$("svg > g:not(.highcharts-legend)").css("display", "none");
$("#chart-container").css(""height", "40px");
```

the problem with this is it hides the chart and leave the legend visible, however it does this:

[image]

when I tried adding this code to override the height of highcharts-legend > rect:

```
$("svg > g:not(.highcharts-legend)").css("display", "none");
$("#chart-container").css(""height", "40px");
$("svg > g.highcharts-legend > rect").attr("style", "height: 27px;");
```

it does this:

[image]

the text and symbol are not showing up.

Comment: I would guess that even though you're excluding the legend class, you're not excluding the contents of it, and therefore it is hiding the contents. You would need to find a way to exclude all of the elements within the legend as well

Comment: the only problem with this, when I set the `chart-container` to 70px it shows the legend with its content and hide everything, however if i make the height to 40px or 30px the legend will become the first image. What I did is add an inline style for `highcharts-legend > rect` to adjust the height but its content won't show up.

Comment: You can disable all elements by options. See result: http://jsfiddle.net/eo1wyyur/. Next solution is use HTML to print legend only. Similar demo which introduces how to print custom legend. http://jsfiddle.net/N3KAC/1/

Answer (score 0):

Hiding an element with `display:none` will hide all the child elements, too. Therefore the only way to achieve your desired effect is to clone the legend, built an highcharts svg with the legend only and hide the original element.

HTML

```
<div>
    <div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto">
    </div>
</div>
<div id="hs-clone" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto">
    <svg id="hs-clone-svg" version="1.1" style="font-family:&quot;Lucida Grande&quot;, &quot;Lucida Sans Unicode&quot;, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:12px;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="453" height="400">
    </svg>
</div>
<button id="showLegendOnly">hide</button>
```

jQuery

```
var $button = $('#showLegendOnly');
var $container = $('#container');
var $clone = $('#hs-clone');
var $cloneSvg = $('#hs-clone-svg');

$button.on('click', function(){
    var $legend = $('.highcharts-legend').clone();
    $cloneSvg.html($legend);
    $container.hide();
    $clone.show();
});
```

Here a **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vy02cj0p/1/)** with the effect. To switch back again you simple cache the container before and replace the clone again.

Comment: your example hide some part of the legend.

Comment: I do not know what exactly you want to hide. I explained how it works and gave you an example.